# SLES12 - How to install zlib package?

Tags: suse, sles

In our research center we recently switched from Debian/Ubuntu to SLES 12. As I am new in SUSE, can someone please help me how to install "zlib" and "zlib-devel" in SLES?

Comment: Maybe read http://opensuse-guide.org/installpackage.php ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as clicking the two following links from a browser on your SLES installation:

- [zlib](http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/openSUSE:Leap:42.1/standard/zlib.ymp?base=openSUSE%3ALeap%3A42.1&query=zlib)
- [zlib-devel](http://software.opensuse.org/ymp/openSUSE:Leap:42.1/standard/zlib-devel.ymp?base=openSUSE%3ALeap%3A42.1&query=zlib-devel)

Comment: The question is about SLES 12, the answer is for SLES 11, which misses the whole point.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/203082/dawid-toton no , answer is for Leap 42.1 buut correct answer is `zypper in zlib`

Answer (score 0):

for SUSE based distribution is package control command `zypper`

you can install zlib and devel files by:

`zypper in libz1 zlib-devel`

I recommend carefully read `man zypper`